# Scrolling user down to content after a slight delay?

Tags: usability

I'm looking at a website which has large headings, pushing the main content down the page. After a slight delay, the content scrolls up the page. This scrolls the main navigation and page header off the page.

**Website:** http://www.diplomatic-cover.com/en/case-study/adecco/

One possible issue could be that the user is reading something, but then the page starts moving. Are there any other usability issues with this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bad idea. There is much potential for user irritation if they're trying to read or click on the top part and it scrolls away.  It's unconventional and unexpected behavior that will make people stop and think, which is generally frowned upon in this business.  A worse case is if users happen to be looking away and not notice that it has scrolled down and have to find the menu (hopefully) by exploration.

My guess is the majority of users will actually scroll back up to see what they've missed, making that initial scroll down somewhat pointless.

From a design perspective, that whole page filling header could tightened up, made smaller with less white space, and still be aesthetically pleasing, allowing more of the real content to be shown on page load, negating the need for this initial auto scroll down.

Answer (score 1):

Most designer's decisions should have strong background. As for me, scrolling on the specified site has strong purpose. It invites a user to futher interaction. Actually, it is marketing page with rich media content, animation and few text. So exploring user behavior is expected. So initial scrolling is a mean for designing flow. Nice!

To be more formal, using usability metrics of *effectiveness* (task accomplishment) and *satisfaction*, the scroll works rather good, as it serves as non-obtrusive interaction guide for the page.

So depending on site type and implementation, scroll could deliver different UX. The main usability issue of auto-scroll is a lack of user control over site.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the auto scroll down does not occur on the homepage is being overlooked.

The assumption being the user has navigated to the "case studies" link and selected a particular case study knowingly (also assuming this isn't being followed from an external link); therefore, the user has already developed a mental map and is prepared to explore the case study.  The auto scroll down leads the user into the study with intention.

I agree, if coming from an external link, this can be disorienting even if the intention is to view the specific case study because entering a new site prompts a desired level of awareness before continuing. Also, the auto scroll only occurs on the "case studies" link and not the others, which makes me think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on the context of the site. In some cases, the target audience may be confused by seemingly random movements which they would usually initiate. However in this case it is probably more acceptable as the target market are much more likely to understand browsers and websites being in the digital field.

I can understand the implementation here as with ever increasing desktop monitor sizes we as designers and developers don't want to leave a load of white space at the side of our sites, yet at the same time we don't want important content to be pushed below the bottom of the viewport due to larger elements on the screen.

This is a clever solution for this particular context in my opinion.